# How can I update a existing war file with additional files using Maven?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

I would like to update an open-source war file in Maven with some additional class files and jar files. I also need to replace one configuration file with my own.

The simplest way I see to do this is copy over the Java source files and configuration files from the base war file and check them into my source repository. This would work, but it requires that I duplicate both source and configuration files. Thus, what I would like to do is build the base war file, check in only that war file, then run a maven build which adds my class files, extra jar files, and replaces one configuration file in the base war. The output of the Maven build would be one war file.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to how I can do this with Maven?

By the way, the base file is from jUDDI - it is juddi-war. I think the answer to the problem does not depend on the particular war file though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use an [overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html). It's intended to add files to an existing WAR.